# get the dynamic input control values from multiple dynamic panels

Tags: jquery, panels

I need your help guys.

My requirement is to get dynamic input control values as an HTML from multiple dynamically created panels. I am using **jquery** to accomplish this work.

**What I have done so far:**

1. I have created a dynamic panel and the dynamic input controls for each dynamic panels. No problem in that part.
2. I have fetched the values of the dynamic input controls and append the values in a HTML in a click event.

**What Issues I'm facing:** The only issue I am getting is, the iteration is not happening while I'm fetching the input values, I'm only able to get the values of the first panel only.

For your reference, I have created a fiddle. Here's the link:

```
[//jsfiddle.net/74z3qunp/][1]
```

Require your kind help into this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have done all my code here //jsfiddle.net/74z3qunp/

Comment: I cant find any object in your code with the id `#hdnPanelinputCount`

Comment: Now i think you should be able to get values from every panel, look here http://jsfiddle.net/74z3qunp/4/

Comment: Now that's the exact thing i wanted, you are the man. Thanks for your help Mr. Andesen.